# In Visual Studio, when I add Korean text to RichTextBox and TextBox, the characters in the RichTextBox have extra space

Tags: richtextbox, cjk

This is how it looks like

[image: This is how it looks like]

can anyone help, please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's simple. Enter Korean text to a RichTextBox using a common font (e.g. Arial or TimesNewRoman). The characters will show up with spaces between them. As you can see below, if the RichTextBox is using a "Korean friendly" font, like "Gulim", the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using the "Gulim" font on the RichTextBox